# PHP laravel frontend how to upload/send csv file to backend api?

Tags: php, laravel

How to send file as form data using laravel `GuzzleHttp\Client`?

My `upload.blade.php`:

```
<!-- is enctype="multipart/form-data required here? -->
<form action="/upload-order" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <p><input type="file" name="work_order" id="work_order"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Upload Work Order"></p>
</form>
```

My web routing:

```
Route::post('/orders-mgmt/upload-order', [ 'uses' => 'UploadController@uploadOrder' ])->name('upload-order');
```

My `UploadController.php`:

```
    public static function uploadOrder(Request $request) {
        if (!($request->hasFile('work_order'))) {
            $message = "No file is selected.";
            return redirect('/orders-mgmt/requests')->with('warnmessage', $message);
        }

        $file= $request->file('work_order');
        $file_path = $file->getPathname();
        $file_uploaded_name = $file->getClientOriginalName(); 
        
        $resBody = (new UploadService($env))->uploadWorkOrderCSV($file_path, $file_uploaded_name);
        ...
    }
```

My `UploadService.php`

```
    public function uploadWorkOrderCSV($file_path, $file_uploaded_name) {
        return json_decode($this->client->request(
            'POST',
            'v1/provision/upload-order',
            [
                'multipart' => [
                    'name' => 'work_order',
                    'contents' => fopen($file_path, 'r'),
                    'filename' => $file_uploaded_name
                ]
            ]
        )->getBody());
    }
```

I got the following error but I think the way I manipulate the form data is already wrong.

```
Type error: Argument 2 passed to GuzzleHttp\Psr7\MultipartStream::addElement() must be of the type array, string given, called in
```

The curl command below works for uploading file, how do I actually build the same request in my `UploadService`?

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:5000/v1/provision/upload-order \
  -F 'work_order=@/C:/Users/kai/Desktop/Local/work_order.csv'
```

Comment: The Content-Type header of `application/vnd.ms-excel` on the “global” level here definitively looks wrong. HTTP File Uploads need to use `multipart/form-data; boundary=…` as the Content Type. Have you tried following this simple example here? https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html?highlight=file#sending-form-files

Comment: I've removed the headers and follow the example using multipart but still getting the error ```Type error: Argument 2 passed to GuzzleHttp\Psr7\MultipartStream::addElement() must be of the type array, string given, called in```

Comment: Which version of Guzzle are you using, is it the latest (currently 7), which those examples are based on? Also, please show what you actually did (not in comments, ad it to the question by editing it) - a mere verbal statement “and follow the example” doesn’t allow us to check if you actually did that correctly, or not.

Comment: have edited my question with the changes I made ```UploadService.php``` & ```UploadController.php```. I'm using guzzle 6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multipart values have to be in a nested array

```
public function uploadWorkOrderCSV($file_path, $file_uploaded_name) {
    return json_decode($this->client->request(
        'POST',
        'v1/provision/upload-order',
        [
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'Content-type' => 'multipart/form-data',
                    'name' => 'work_order',
                    'contents' => fopen($file_path, 'r'),
                    'filename' => $file_uploaded_name
                ]                 
            ]
            
        ]
    )->getBody());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You May Easy Call Multipart Api for image uploading directly using use GuzzleHttp\Client;

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Utils;
use File;

        $filename = $req->file('file1')->getClientOriginalName();
        $getfilePath  = $req->file('file1')->getRealPath();
        $client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:8045/api/uploadImages', [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'image',
            'contents' => fopen($getfilePath, 'r')
        ],
        // 'headers'  => [
        //      'Content-Type' => '<Content-type header>'
        //  ]
       
    ]
]);
echo $response->getStatusCode();
$bodyresponcs = $response->getBody();
$result = json_decode($bodyresponcs);
print_r($result->status);
```

your Form in view file

```
<form action="/postsubmit" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
@csrf
<input type="file"  name="file1"   />
<button type="submit" class="btn long">Submit</button>
</form>
```